# What does 'UNKNOWN' permission mean in GRANT command?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In the following sql statement what does 'UNKNOWN' mean ?
I've connected redshift to sql workbench. When I view the table in DB Explorer, i see the following statement after CREATE statement.

```
GRANT UNKNOWN, SELECT ON sample_t TO group readonly_group;
```

Comment: Does this code actually run? UNKNOWN is not valid syntax as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I didn't wrote it, i just saw while viewing sql source of table in database explorer.

Answer (score 1):

The [GRANT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GRANT.html) documentation page does *not* show an entry for `UNKNOWN`:

```
GRANT { { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE | REFERENCES } [,...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { [ TABLE ] table_name [, ...] | ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO { username [ WITH GRANT OPTION ] | GROUP group_name | PUBLIC } [, ...]

GRANT { { CREATE | TEMPORARY | TEMP } [,...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON DATABASE db_name [, ...]
    TO { username [ WITH GRANT OPTION ] | GROUP group_name | PUBLIC } [, ...]

GRANT { { CREATE | USAGE } [,...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON SCHEMA schema_name [, ...]
    TO { username [ WITH GRANT OPTION ] | GROUP group_name | PUBLIC } [, ...]

GRANT { EXECUTE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { FUNCTION function_name ( [ [ argname ] argtype [, ...] ] ) [, ...] | ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO { username [ WITH GRANT OPTION ] | GROUP group_name | PUBLIC } [, ...]

GRANT { EXECUTE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { PROCEDURE procedure_name ( [ [ argname ] argtype [, ...] ] ) [, ...] | ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO { username [ WITH GRANT OPTION ] | GROUP group_name | PUBLIC } [, ...]

GRANT USAGE 
    ON LANGUAGE language_name [, ...]
    TO { username [ WITH GRANT OPTION ] | GROUP group_name | PUBLIC } [, ...]
```

Comment: But it shows while viewing sql source of table in database explorer in sql workbench. Why?

Comment: It might be the result of how SQL Workbench interprets the results, with an assumption that the database is PostgreSQL rather than Amazon Redshift. This might help: [How to View Permissions in Amazon Redshift](https://chartio.com/learn/amazon-redshift/how-to-view-permissions-in-amazon-redshift/)

Comment: i agree with john.